# How do I get Largest value from a table with all columns containing numeric values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle with all columns containing numeric value
I need a query or (PL\sql script)to find largest number from a table 
please help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
declare
maxNumCol nubmer;
maxNum nubmer := 0;
begin
for aCol in (select column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and column_type = 'NUMBER') loop
   execute immediate 'select max('||aCol.column_name||') from MY_TABLE' into maxNumCol;
   maxNum := greatest(maxNum, maxNumCol);
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(maxNum);
end;
```

Maybe you can use also this, but I am not sure:

```
select greatest(max(col_a), max(col_b), max(col_c)) from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Without procedural script

```
select MAX(num)
from
(
select colA as num
from test
union
select colB
from test
union
Select colC
from test
union
.
.

)  x
```